# Integrate PHP to Tableau Server (apache Webserver?)

Tags: php, apache, webserver, tableau-api, windows-server-2012

I have following problem: 
Tableau server is installed and works fine, I was looking into getting php working so I could access the Database from a web interface. I am used to the apache structure on Linux but the server is running Windows 2012 and I don't manage to understand how Tableau Installed it's own apache? Therefore I am a bit lost. If someone could guide me in the right direction? 
I can host files in the Htdocs folder but if I want to execute PHP it just comments it out since it is not configured/ installed.
Is someone familiar with getting php to work without installing a seperate apache or IIS?

Comment: When you say `"access the Database from a web interface"`, what are you referring to? Accessing postgres that Tableau Server runs or a data source you have extracted to Tableau Server? Or possibly creating your own interface for accessing specific reports?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the answer. It is not relevant but I want to access the Postgres later on. The thing is php should be available on any web page since I plan to build more apps and not limiting myself to just Tableau.
I hope this makes it more clear.